# Property [model] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Tengo estos 3 modelos en laravel 7 e intento hacer las relaciones entre ellos.

UserCar
Brand
CarModel

La relación lógica seria en "UserCar" tengo N registros que corresponden a una marca (Brand) y dicha marca a su vez tiene N modelos de coches (CarModel).

Como la relación entre marca y modelo la tengo en CarModel, en el modelo UserCar solo guardo
el modelo, ya que con una relación debo poder acceder a la marca.

Para ello tengo estas relaciones
**Modelo Brand**

```
public function models()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CarModel');
}
```

**Modelo CarModel**

```
public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand');
}
```

Ahora me falta la relación donde le digo que **UserCar** tiene 1 marca, entiendo que es una relación 1 a 1 y debe ser asi

```
    public function model() 
    {
    return $this->hasOne('App\CarModel');
    }
```

El problema lo tengo, para acceder a la relación, si hago esto desde tinker

```
$a = App\UserCar::where('id',3)->get();
```

Esto me devuelve un registro, y entonces hago

```
$a->model;
```

Y me dice que dicha propiedad no existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta que tienes esta mal.

Cuando al final de la misma haces uso de `get` estarías obteniendo una colección de objetos (*así ese id solo retorne 1 objeto*) por lo cual primero deberías iterar y posterior tratar de acceder a la relación deseada para cada objeto obtenido; mas o menos así:

```
$a = App\UserCar::where('id',3)->get();

foreach ($a as $elemento) {
    $elemento->relacion;
}
```

Pero honestamente eso no hace sentido, desde el momento en que la consulta inicial plantea   retornar solo un elemento es decir aquel que tenga el id número 3; entonces con hacer lo siguiente alcanza:

```
$a = App\UserCar::whereId(3)->first();

$a->relacion;
```

Comment: muchas gracias @BetaM ya ví mi fallo. gracias