# Imprimir array de eloquent en una vista

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

tengo este problema. tengo una funcion que rescata datos y hace los inner Join de forma correcta. pero al momento de enviarlo a la vista me da error.

Esta es la funcion del controlador.

```
    public function show($id){

    $mascota = mascota::query()
    ->select ('mascotas.nombreMascota','mascotas.foto','mascotas.estadoVacuna','razas.raza')
    ->from ('mascotas')
    ->Join('razas','mascotas.id_raza','=','razas.id')
    ->where('mascotas.id','=',$id)
    ->get();

    //return $mascota;

    return view('mascotas.show',compact('mascota'));

}
```

Esta es la vista:

```
@section('title','Mascota '. $mascota->nombreMascota)

@section('content')
<h1>Pagina de la mascota {{$mascota->nombreMascota}}</h1>
<a href="{{route('mascotas.index')}}">Ver lista de mascotas</a>
<br>
<a href="{{route('mascotas.edit', $mascota)}}">Editar mascota</a>

<p><strong>Nombre:</strong> {{$mascota->nombreMascota}}
<p><img src="{{$mascota->foto}}" width="200" height="200"></p>
<p><strong>Vacunado:</strong> {{$mascota->estadoVacuna}}</p>
<p><strong>Raza:</strong> {{$mascota->raza}}
@endsection
```

Estas son las rutas:

```
    Route::get('mascotas', 'index')->name('mascotas.index');
    Route::get('mascotas/create', 'create')->name('mascotas.create');
    Route::post('mascotas','store')->name('mascotas.store');
    Route::get('mascotas/{id}', 'show')->name('mascotas.show');
    Route::get('mascotas/{id}/edit', 'edit')->name('mascotas.edit');
    Route::put('mascotas/{id}','update')->name('mascotas.update');

});
```

Este es el error que me entrega:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y pueden verificar el arreglo cuando lo imprimo quitando el comentario de return mascota.

```
[{"nombreMascota":"Bunny","foto":"sinfoto","estadoVacuna":"si","raza":"Bulldog"}]
```

Comment: Es porque tenés una colección en esa variable. Puedes usar `first()` en vez de `get()` en la consulta si solo quieres un objeto, y no una colección. Si sí quieres una colección, en la vista tendrás que hacer un loop sobre ella para acceder a las propiedades de cada objeto

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono perfecto, solo tuve que solicitar la tabla id para enviarla a la vista por que no la estaba trayendo con el first :D

Comment: Entonces... ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Property \[model\] does not exist on this collection instance](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401822/property-model-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance)